# How to play 360 video from server URL?

Tags: android, android-video-player, video-player, 360-degrees

I am trying to implement `360 video player` in my upcoming app. In which the 360 video is coming from server url.

The problem is the video is not playing. when its coming from live `URL`.

I tried to implement this both `library`.

1. https://github.com/fbsamples/360-video-player-for-android
2. http://www.panframe.com/

The problem is both is working only if the video is stored locally in android device. But not working with live server `URL`.

If anyone implemented this please guide me.

Comment: have you tried  https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer may it will help you

Comment: try this https://github.com/ashqal/MD360Player4Android